# onChange not firing when deleting the input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I'm facing an issue where i cannot get the `onChange` to fire when i delete the input value by highlighting the value and pressing delete button (Or Ctrl+a+Delete). However `onChange` fires when deleting the value using just the delete button (One by one) How can i get my input to fire the `onChange` function when i delete the input value at once (By selecting the whole string/int)

```
<Form.Control  type="text" value={this.state.value !== "" ? this.state.value : this.state.groupName} className="input_text" onChange={this.onChange} required />
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole component code to figure out the issue?

Comment: Typically `onInput` is used for incremental keyboard presses, whereas `onChange` is used for when an input element is blurred.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Not sure what is the rest of the logic. but I think that `this.state.groupName`
causing the problem.

Because it sets the value to that groupName when the value is empty.
And then after if you try to delete the whole text by selecting, It'll fall back to that groupName which is the same value you had so it won't delete the text as a whole. 
But you can delete one by one.